# Getting "undefined method 'changed?'" error on vmc push after latest upgrade

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

After upgrading to vmc 0.4.4 I can't do push on my Sinatra app anymore
Any known fixes?

Time of crash:
  2012-12-06 13:14:20 -0800

NoMethodError: undefined method `changed?' for #

vmc-0.4.4/lib/vmc/cli/app/push/sync.rb:13:in `display_changes'
vmc-0.4.4/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:89:in`sync_app'
vmc-0.4.4/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:80:in `push'
mothership-0.3.4/lib/mothership/base.rb:61:in`run'
mothership-0.3.4/lib/mothership/command.rb:68:in `block in invoke'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.17/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:113:in`call'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.17/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Manifests>'
mothership-0.3.4/lib/mothership/callbacks.rb:74:in`with_filters'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.4.17/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:112:in `block in <class:Manifests>'
mothership-0.3.4/lib/mothership/command.rb:78:in`instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.4/lib/mothership/command.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in invoke'
mothership-0.3.4/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in`instance_exec'
mothership-0.3.4/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `invoke'
mothership-0.3.4/lib/mothership/base.rb:50:in`execute'
vmc-0.4.4/lib/vmc/cli.rb:106:in `execute'
mothership-0.3.4/lib/mothership.rb:45:in`start'
vmc-0.4.4/bin/vmc:11:in `<top (required)>'
ruby-1.9.2-p290@main1.9/bin/vmc:23:in`load'
ruby-1.9.2-p290@main1.9/bin/vmc:23:in `'

Comment: I'm getting the same with a Grails app deployed as standalone using tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you experience any issues with vmc 0.4.x at all, I advice you install the legacy version (0.3.23). You can remove 0.4.4 entirely or you can call a specific version (0.3.23 in this case) using the following syntax..

```
vmc _0.3.23_ <command>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Is there any official info on that issue? Any approved path of upgrade with already deployed apps?

Comment: I believe the latest version, 0.4.5, fixes this issue.